# Change Popper.js Tooltip Title on Click

Tags: click, tooltip, popper

I swear I searched and did not find this question. Sorry if I have done a mistake!

**ATTENTION**: I want to use JavaScript ONLY! I don't want to include jQuery library! There are many examples out there using jQuery, but they don't help me.

**Problem**: I am creating a website and I am using Bootstrap 5 + Popper. I have some E-Mail addresses written in the content. Each E-Mail address is embedded within an HTML anchor. For each E-Mail address I show a "Copy address" tooltip on hovering it. When the anchor text (the E-Mail address) is clicked I want to copy the Email-Adress into the clipboard so the user can paste it into whatever E-Mail client they use. After clicking the E-Mail address the tooltip title should be changed to "Copied" as confirmation for the user.

HTML code:

```
<a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-bs-original-title="Copy address">office@example.com</a>
...
<!-- This input text field is used to copy the text (E-Mail addresses) via JavaScript -->
<input type="text" id="copy_input" readonly style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">
```

The JavaScript initialization for the Popper tooltip (just as it is on the Bootstrap page for Tooltip):

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
});
```

And here goes my JavaScript code that can copy the E-Mail address into the clipboard BUT IS NOT ABLE to change the tooltip title:

```
tooltipTriggerList.forEach(function(alink) {
    alink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const copy_input = document.querySelector('#copy_input');
        copy_input.value = alink.textContent.trim();
        copy_input.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        copy_input.value = '';
        alink.setAttribute('data-bs-original-title', 'Copied');
        alink.setAttribute('title', 'Copied');  // just to be sure...
        alink.show();  // I thought show() would re-display the changed title, but no!
    });
});
```

Unfortunately the tooltip title is not changed by the listener function above.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The error relies on that the show method should be called on the tooltip object insted of the link element

```js
tooltipTriggerList.forEach(function(alink) {
    alink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do the copy logic ....
    
        // change title for tooltip
        alink.setAttribute('data-bs-original-title', 'Copied');
    
        // show the tooltip with the new title
        bootstrap.Tooltip.getInstance(alink).show()
    });
});
```